# None is printing unnecessarily

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class School:
    school_name='gtti'
    def __init__(self,name,marks):
        self.name=name
        self.marks=marks
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    @classmethod
    def get_school(cls):
        return cls.school_name
    @staticmethod
    def number_print(number):
        print("the number is ",number)
print(School.get_school())
print(School.number_print(6))
```

The output printing as '
gtti
the number is  6
None

Why there is extra **None** is printing in jupyter notebook

Comment: The function `number_print` is returning nothing that's why there's a `None` in the output.

Comment: ``School.number_print(6)`` prints 6 and returns None. The outer ``print`` thus prints None.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine, its because you printed out the function call too, which does not return anything

```
class School:
    school_name='gtti'
    def __init__(self,name,marks):
       self.name=name
       self.marks=marks
    def get_name(self):
       return self.name
    @classmethod
    def get_school(cls):
       return cls.school_name
    @staticmethod
    def number_print(number):
       print("the number is ",number)
                
print(School.get_school())
School.number_print(6)
```